# google universal analytics events sent but not received by analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am using google universal analytics on my website. Although POST requests seem to be sent correctly there are no tracked events in my analytics account.

This is the post request (url and analytics id are masked)

```
Request URL:http://www.google-analytics.com/collect
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:120
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:www.google-analytics.com
Origin:http://www.xxxxxxxx.com
Referer:http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
v:1
tid:UA-xxxxxxxxx-1
cid:3E1FA9FE-28B3-7032-1714-5083DD155FCF
t:click
ec:link
ea:outbound_link
el:startpage
ev:headline
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:35
Content-Type:image/gif
Date:Fri, 10 May 2013 13:25:44 GMT
Expires:Mon, 07 Aug 1995 23:30:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Sun, 17 May 1998 03:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:GFE/2.0
Via:1.0 non_disclosed:3128 (squid)
X-Cache:MISS from non_disclosed
X-Cache-Lookup:MISS from non_disclosed:3128
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
```

Does anyone have a clue what's going on here? Thanks!

Jesse

#### UPDATE

I was trying to send the request via jquery's $.post method first. You can see the result above. Nothing has been tracked by Google Analytics.

Now I switched to this method as described in the analytics.js developer guide

```
function trackOutboundLink(link, event_hittype, event_category, event_action, event_value) {
ga('send', event_hittype, {
    'clientId' : clientId,
    'eventCategory' : event_category,
    'eventAction' : event_action,
    'eventLabel' : link.href,
    'eventValue' : event_value,
    'hitCallback' : function () {
        // document.location = link.href;
    }
});

    window.open(
        link.href,
        '_blank'
    );
}
```

The generated request looks like this:

```
Request URL:http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j8&a=217518556&t=event&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.de%2F&ul=de&de=UTF-8&dt=Foosd=24-bit&sr=1440x900&vp=1439x747&je=1&fl=11.7%20r700&ec=OutboundLinkClick&ea=Startpage&el=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.de&ev=Headline&_u=OCC~&cid=283560406.1367606414&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&z=496696042
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:www.google-analytics.com
Referer:http://www.mywebsite.de/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
v:1
_v:j8
a:217518556
t:event
dl:http://www.mywebsite.de/
ul:de
de:UTF-8
dt:Foo
sd:24-bit
sr:1440x900
vp:1439x747
je:1
fl:11.7 r700
ec:OutboundLinkClick
ea:Startpage
el:http://test.de
ev:Headline
_u:OCC~
cid:283560406.1367606414
tid:UA-XXXXXXXX-1
z:496696042
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Age:120360
Cache-Control:private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate
Content-Length:35
Content-Type:image/gif
Date:Thu, 16 May 2013 00:10:08 GMT
Expires:Mon, 07 Aug 1995 23:30:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Sun, 17 May 1998 03:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:GFE/2.0
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
```

Event is fired correctly while the target link is opened in a new window. Status is 200 for the request.

Guess what, I do not get any events tracked in google Analytics. I double-checked the UA code and I cannot imagine any filter in analytics because I did not set one up.

This method is online since yesterday (24 hours). I don't know what's the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here we go.
It seems as if the problem was piping the event through another method.

I finally managed to make it work with this setup:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'mydomain.com');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
        var clientId = '';
        ga(function (tracker) {
            clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

and then in the view

```
<a href="http://www.outboundwebsite.com" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'outbound_startpage', 'click', 'headline')" target="_blank">Outbound headline link on my startpage</a>
```

All relevant data including unique user id is applied to the event and fired correctly. You can see data flowing in immediately when looking at the realtime event view in google analytics.

Thanks for your help guys.

By the way: There is a nice tutorial over at http://blog.kissmetrics.com/universal-analytics

Comment: This was an interesting resolution, however in my case, I am only seeing about 1:20 requests. On my home machine I see the requests instantly with a 1:1. On my remote machines, I get random results. This has been very elusive and problematic.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I do see that's off is `t:click`.  If it were an event it would show `t:event`

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#event

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. You are right it must be t:event but nonetheless it is not working. I tried this request from the website but nothing happens in my analytics account
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-12312312-1&cid=283560406.1367606414&t=event&ec=link&ea=click&el=outbound_detailpage&ev=image

Comment: i assume you did obvious checks like make sure the account number is right, no filters setup that would reject it, etc.?  How long are you waiting to check if it shows up? It can take up to 24 hours to show up.  Did you try outputting the same custom code via the js imp to compare request urls? if so, did you try seeing if the same thing vs js works?

Comment: What do you mean by "outputting the same custom code via the js imp to compare request urls"?

Comment: @Jesse Okay, so you are currently doing this via server-side code, e.g. with a curl request, or else using some API to build the query string and send it, yeah? I assume so because that's the only way it would be a POST request.  Well the standard implementation is via javascript like on a web page (which is a GET request).  So what you can do is make a test webpage with the javascript version of your code and load the web page and compare requests.

Comment: @jesse stupid question- you are masking the account number only here and not in your real code,  yes?